# RESTful API design - using a resource URI vs an ID

Tags: rest, server, client, uri, api-design

this is my first post, so please bear with me.

I am designing a new RESTful API and I have two design choices in how my clients interact with resources that they create.

As an example, I have a resource: "book", which is a simple, singleton resource.

Creating a new book is very simple:

```
POST https://api.mydomain.com/book
```

I know I can also use PUT if I want the operation to be idempotent.

This question is solely about the 200 OK response options, returning either:

1. an anonymous resource identifier (UUID) of the created "book":

   {

   book_id = 12345-67890

   title = "a fantastic story"

   }
2. a full FQDN URI to the created "book":

   {

   book_uri = "https://mylibrary.mydomain.com/upstairs/book/12345-67890

   title = "a fantastic story"

   }

This of course significantly effects the subsequent manipulation of the "book" by the client.

To get the title of the above book, the client API calls would be either:

1. GET [https://api.mydomain.com/book/{book-id}](https://api.mydomain.com/book/%7Bbook-id%7D)

   Example: GET https://api.mydomain.com/book/12345-67890

Notes: The client will always use the same endpoint as the POST call, with the book-id simply appended.

2. GET {book-uri}

   Example: GET https://mylibrary.mydomain.com/upstairs/book/12345-67890

Notes: The client will use the {book-uri} object variable directly from the POST response.  Importantly, the returned {book-uri) may be a completely different URI to that of the POST used to create the "book".

So my questions (please) are:

Q1) which is the better model for the client to use and why?

Q2) can you see any issues with using Option 2 in a high volume, commercial system?

Thanks for any help and answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> can you see any issues with using Option 2 in a high volume, commercial system?

So, Option 2, where the HTTP response includes a URI for the newly created resource, is how the web itself works, and the web seems to be doing pretty well as a high volume commercial system.

Note also that option #2 allows the server to control its URIs.  For instance, if you later decide that you want to revise the resource model, and use different spellings for the resource identifiers, then you can do that without needing to make any changes to the client.

You can also introduce, for example, a URI shortening component, because again you've got an identifier with standardized rules for how it works.

You don't necessarily need to use a full URI - we've also got standardized rules for how a URI fragment can be used to compute a URI in a given context, so you'll likely have options like

```
{
book_uri = "/upstairs/book/12345-67890",
title = "a fantastic story"
}
```

... depending on whether or not the book resource is staged on the same host as the resource that handles the POST request.

Is this better?  That's going to depend on what tradeoffs you need to make, and how much you value each of the benefits versus the costs.

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction. -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)

Comment: I think option 2 follows the principle of "URI as the only identifier of the resource". This also means that the rest apis should be level 3 compliant from the [4 maturity models of REST apis](https://blog.restcase.com/4-maturity-levels-of-rest-api-design/). Is that right?